# Compiling LUDecompsitionTest from apache common math without common-math3-3.3.jar and maven

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

```
 javac -cp .:/dcsdata/home/hdokani2/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar:/dcsdata/home/hdokani2/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/dcsdata/home/hdokani2/Desktop/cs527/commons-math3-3.3.jar LUDecompositionTest.java
```

This works for me, but I need to make some changes to main `src/main/java/org/commons/math3/linear/LUDecomposition.java` and accordingly I want to make tests fail. Therefore I need all the main files to be compiled also, so I removed `common-math3-3.3.jar` and added all the files from `src/main/java` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use

```
mvn -Dtest=LUDecompositionTest
```

from the top level of the source distribution (or a checkout of the development sources or a release tag).  If you don't want to use maven, but you are willing to use Ant, there is a build.xml included with the source and you can edit the compile.tests target to include only the test you want to execute.  Just eliminate the wildcards and specify

```
<include name="**/*LUDecompositionTest.java"/>
```

then do

```
ant clean test
```

If you really want to do this on the command line without either Ant or Maven, you need to create a new jar including your changes and put jar on the classpath above in place of the distribution jar.